# Determinant of a jacobian

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I have the following problem.The jacobian matrix is given in the image below.I just cannot seem to figure out how they arrived at the determinant.Can anyone show the steps or elaborate the procedure?
[image: Jacobian Matrix and its determinant]